# ASPX (c# behind) Value Passing Between Page Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I my default.aspx have the following code in a page:

```
Label1.Text = datatable.Rows[0].Field<string>(1);

Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx?Parameter=" + Label1.Text);
```

In my welcome.aspx page, I have the following page_load code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label2.Text = Request.QueryString["Parameter"].ToString() + ", welcome to the website!";
        }
```

When I view the website in a browser, on the Welcome page, I can see in the URL, that the parameter has been passed, however the label text is not updated. It almost seems like the page_load code isn't being run?

As requested, the aspx of the welcome page is below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 503px;
            height: 249px;
            margin-left: 67px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div style="margin-left: 280px">

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <img alt="" class="auto-style1" src="Logo.jpg" /><br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">testing</asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody explain why, and how to fix it?

Comment: can you show us your aspx code? if you set a variable string x = Request.QueryString["Parameter"], does it return a value? you do not need to ToString again

Comment: @Alander I have added the aspx of welcome.aspx as requested

Comment: does string x = Request.QueryString["Parameter"]; returns null if you insert a breakpoint?

Comment: @Alander I have tried populating a variable and checking it with a breakpoint, but the breakpoint never fires, so I am sure that the page_load code never runs.

Comment: Is Page Caching turned on?

Comment: no, its not. deleting and re-creating the page fixed it, although i dont understand why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session State could be a better choice for that particular scenario, because you will need it whenever user lands on the WelcomePage.

```
Session["Parameter"] = datatable.Rows[0].Field<string>(1); 
// Set a break point at Redirect, and check to make value is assigned 
// to Session["Parameter"] before redirecting.
Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label2.Text = Session["Parameter"] + ", welcome to the website!"; 
}
```

***Note:*** If the above solution doesn't solve the problem, the worst case you just ***delete*** `Welcome.aspx`, ***create*** a new one without Master Page, and see Page_Load event fires.

Comment: This gives exactly the same issue. I also put a breakpoint on the Label2 = statement in the page_load and this never fires.

Comment: `<%@ Page Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Welcome.aspx.cs" ... %>` Could you ensure that `AutoEventWireup` is set to true at `Welcome.aspx`.

Comment: Yes this is set to true in the pages. I have also tried adding to web.config, but still the same result

Comment: Could you delete that `Welcome.aspx`, create a new one without Master Page, and see `Page_Load` event fires? Also, make sure you are in Debug mode instead of Release mode.

Comment: I have no idea why, but deleting and re-creating the welcome page seems to have fixed it. Thank you! If you convert the comment into an answer, I will make it as the answer.